# TypeInitializationException was unhandled #2

Tags: c#

I'm creating a DLL for a application that I make.
But I got a error when I added the DLL as refference to the console Application but do not know what it means this is the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe

And this is my dll class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace Steap
{
    public class SteapAPI
    {
        public static String URL
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(URL + "?xml=1&l=english");

        public int getSteamID64()
        {
            int ID = 0;
            r.ReadToFollowing("steamID64");
            ID = r.ReadContentAsInt();
            return ID;
        }

        public string getSteamID()
        {
            string ID = String.Empty;
            r.ReadToFollowing("steamID");
            ID = r.ReadContentAsString();
            return ID;
        }

        public int getVac()
        {
            int Vac = 0;
            r.ReadToFollowing("vacBanned");
            Vac = r.ReadContentAsInt();
            return Vac;
        }

        public bool hasVac()
        {
            if (getVac() == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }


        // =================== [ Aliases

        public string getName()
        {
            return getSteamID();
        }
    }
}
```

Console application code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Steap;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SteapAPI sapi = new SteapAPI(); // TypeInitializationException was unhandled error here
            SteapAPI.URL = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/bluesephire";
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong or what is missing

Comment: Can you tell us what line you get the error on?

Comment: You can't do `public static XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(URL + "?xml=1&l=english");` because `URL` hasn't been assigned.

Comment: Ron Beyer, In the console application by "SteapAPI sapi = new SteapAPI();"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

You have exception during initialization of static field of your class that leads to failure to load the class and hence the `TypeInitializationException` exception.

Particular line:

```
public static XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(URL + "?xml=1&l=english");
```

`URL` is not initialized at the time method called (and even if it would have static value like `URL=@"c:\file.txt"` there is no guarantee that one field will be initialized first.

Note from that point any access to the `SteapAPI` class will throw the `TypeInitializationException` even if it is not touching fields directly involved into original exception.

Comment: So how can I fix this properly? is there a way to put it in this line:
SteapAPI sapi = new SteapAPI(HERE);

Comment: @JoeydeVries easiest would be to not make them static if it works for you... If not Making whole class singleton (or just fields you interested in) using `Lazy<T>` class may be an option.

Comment: By non static I cannot access URL and either I never heard of Lazy<T> also googling gives my MSDN but cant get it

Comment: @JoeydeVries yes, you can, you access it by sapi.URL, and it should be an instance property anyway, not static because if you used 2 copies of the API one would overwrite the other with a different URL.

Comment: @RonBeyer I mean in the DLL Class I cant.

Comment: @JoeydeVries I think you are misunderstanding what static fields are, the way you use it in the DLL is downright dangerous, and would only work if there were never 2 instances of the API. The fields need to be instance fields, not static ones, and you can access them just like you are accessing the fields now.

Comment: @RonBeyer See this screen shot from the error: http://prntscr.com/6zrooa

Comment: @JoeydeVries you have to make the XMLReader an instance field as well (not static), not just the URL property.

Comment: @RonBeyer 

public static String URL
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(URL + "?xml=1&l=english");

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: @JoeydeVries **BOTH** have to be instance, not one or the other, both. Not sure how I can explain it more, but you can't have one static and one instance, they *both* need to be defined **without** the static keyword. I will post an answer with the code.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you shouldn't be using static fields. Static fields will cause huge problems if you ever create two `SteapAPI` objects, in that when you set one URL, it will overwrite the other one, and you'll never be able to re-initialize the `XmlReader`.

Here is how the API class should be rewritten to be a full instance class:

```
namespace Steap
{
    public class SteapAPI
    {
        public String URL
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public XmlReader r;

        public SteapAPI(string url)
        {
            URL = url;
            //NOTE: This is wrong! You can't create an XmlReader with a URL
            //and expect it to fetch a web resource.
            r = XmlReader.Create(URL + "?xml=1&l=english");
        }

        public int getSteamID64()
        {
            int ID = 0;
            r.ReadToFollowing("steamID64");
            ID = r.ReadContentAsInt();
            return ID;
        }

        public string getSteamID()
        {
            string ID = String.Empty;
            r.ReadToFollowing("steamID");
            ID = r.ReadContentAsString();
            return ID;
        }

        public int getVac()
        {
            int Vac = 0;
            r.ReadToFollowing("vacBanned");
            Vac = r.ReadContentAsInt();
            return Vac;
        }

        public bool hasVac()
        {
            if (getVac() == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }


        // =================== [ Aliases

        public string getName()
        {
            return getSteamID();
        }
    }
```

And then to use it in your program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SteapAPI sapi = new SteapAPI("http://steamcommunity.com/id/bluesephire");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Its a minor change but the benefits are huge, you should learn more about using constructors and the drawbacks of static fields/properties as it applies to multiple instances. Just remember, a static field/property of a non-static class is *shared between all "instances" of the class, so setting one will set all "instances" of that class to the new value*. This is especially important when doing I/O operations and file/resource reading/writing.

Comment: When I call like any method it gives: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Comment: @JoeydeVries because XmlReader.Create() does not take a web address, you need to download the file before creating the reader. It shouldn't be named URL, it should be named URI, and its a local resource file you have to pass to it.

Comment: Oke thanks for your help I will try that now!

Comment: but it's a dll I cannot download files so I need to download the file locally but where?

Comment: You need to form the entire request (with the ?xml=...) and make a WebRequest or HttpRequest to get the data returned by the query, then save that XML to a file, and pass it into the API. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think I made the request that was not hard but the file part is hard http://prntscr.com/6zs082

Comment: File.WriteAllText, save it to a local temp file, and then pass the location of that file to the XmlReader.

Comment: Still doesnt work: http://prntscr.com/700ihx Code: http://prntscr.com/700iul

Comment: What is in the file that you created? It should be a well-formed XML document. If its JSON or something else, then you have to do things differently.

Comment: How should I do that? I create a XML file with the Xml in it and when I open that file in chrome it looks the same as the web url

Comment: I fixed it my self, It was a long rid but 1 part of the problem was XMLReader can only read from top to bottom and no randomly trought the file also I was right that I can stream the file from the web and this is my final code as fix http://pastebin.com/JURKr7XK I will optimize it later on but Im good to go for now